# Enforce acl at Project level dataset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

How to define acl for bigquery datasets. User can only access dataset created by him (Should not be able to access any other user datasets) but service account can access any datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts) regarding `Granting roles to a service account for specific resources` - you can grant roles to a service account so that the service account has permission to complete specific actions on the resources in your Cloud Platform project.

To see all BigQuery's Cloud Identity and Access Management roles and permissions, visit [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control). You can also assign roles at the dataset level to provide access only to one or more datasets.

You can grant the permission with the following command:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <YOUR_PROJECT_ID> --member "serviceAccount:<NAME>@<YOUR_PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role "roles/bigquery.<ROLE>"
```

I hope it helps you.